# Changing a specific character in a line

Tags: awk, vim

### Input

- Every line is separated into 8 parts by semicolons
- Every part can include words,numbers,space etc.

### Output

I am trying to replace the space in the 6th part with a semicolon, thus separating the line again, making the total number of parts 9.

### Example

```
1;30;68;Az LEMda;Ads Awdsâ;1 Bethesda, Galilea, Impe Mkals;29;63
264;16 October 1978;2 April 2005;AAz Jgfg adal II;Madwl Qózca Asdtyła;20 May 1920 Maklo, Polasn;58;84
```

would end up like

```
1;30;68;Az LEMda;Ads Awdsâ;1;Bethesda, Galilea, Impe Mkals;29;63
264;16 October 1978;2 April 2005;AAz Jgfg adal II;Madwl Qózca Asdtyła;20;May 1920 Maklo, Polasn;58;84
```

### Attempts

I tried to find the space using anything ranging from regex to `\zs` but failed. The closest I came was finding the 5th semicolon.

```
%s/\(.\{-};\zs\)\{5}/;/g
```

But I need to find the space that comes after the number that comes after the 5th semicolon, so this kind of thinking got me nowhere and now I am trying to find the space in the parts that I defined earlier.

I could put `awk` into vim but then again I am fairly new with it. I managed to find the 6th part and change the space into a semicolon, but then it changes all the spaces, not just the first one.

```
:%! awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/ /, ";", $6)} 1'
```

How can I just change the first space in the 6th part?

Comment: `sub` in place of `gsub` should replace only the first occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim:

```
%s/^\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}[^ ;]*\)\s/\1;/
```

which means:

- Select as `\1`

  - from the beginning of the line `^`
  - five times `\{5\}` a string of non-semicolons followed by a semicolon
  - plus in the 6th field leading characters which are neither a semicolon nor a space
- Followed by a space
- Replace with what was selected as `\1` and a semicolon.

Comment: And what if I wanted to put the semicolon in the space after the last digit in the 6th part?

Comment: `%s/^\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}[^;]*[0-9]\)\s\([^0-9;]*;\)/\1;\3/` -- meaning that now `\1` can include spaces and must end with a digit, and there can be no more digits before the semicolon which ends the 6th field. Note that the rest of the 6th field is `\3` because it's the 3rd time `\(` appears in the pattern.